# Spring MVC 3 - design of UDP Server+HTTP application

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, udp

I'm designing an application that uses UDP to receive datagram packets, handles them and allows administrator to view parsed data.

For this moment, I've created a single thread for receiving UDP packets. The thread is stored in ServletContext, started on ServletContextListener's contextInitialized(). My next step should be parsing it, but as long as I want to use Spring's services (@Service), I have no idea how to inject reference to specified services in receiver's thread.

I know that I can get ServletContext's reference in Service and set reference in receiver's thread to created Service, but is it correct way to do this? (is there a better way?)

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would design a service-like class that launches and manages the thread listening for UDP packets.

This service would then be started from your Spring context, which you can have loaded with [`ContextLoaderListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html).

This way, you can develop the UDP layer in a way that has nothing to do with a web application - and make it possible to re-use it in a non-web context.

Starting the thread yourself in a listener and sticking it in the ServletContext sounds like a mix of concerns.

Comment: I've totally missed that Spring has it own on-load-listener. Maybe that's because I'm into Spring for one week, so thank you for fast anwser.